# Google Checkout level-2 integration using Checkout Java SDK on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-checkout

I've tried this integration using two approaches and I can get neither to work.

When using the "Notification Serial Number" setting, which allows you to get away with not having an SSL cert on the GAE end, the callback from GAE to Checkout takes so long to happen that I get DeadlineExceededExceptions after about 1 min 12 secs.

When using the "Notification as XML (Requires an HTTPS URL)" setting, the SSL cert isn't valid and Checkout times out on the connection:

```
We encountered an error trying to access your server at https://VERSION.APP_ID.appspot.com/googleCheckout -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'TIMEOUT' connecting to url 'https://VERSION.APP_ID.appspot.com/googleCheckout'.
```

When going to that URL in a browser, the browser warns that the certificate is invalid, but then claims it *should* be valid:

```
The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.appspot.com , *.*.appspot.com , appspot.com  

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

Comment: I don't use GAE nor do I do JAVA (therefore caveat emptor). It seems odd that the callback (sending a serial # to obtain the data) takes that long - do you have any insight to why that is - re: have you tried/tested it using some (other, not using GAE, perhaps a local box) resource to see/compare?

Comment: Are you really telling Checkout to contact "https://VERSION.APP_ID.appspot.com/googleCheckout"? ;)

Comment: @TomTasche well no obviously that's really my actual version number and app ID, eg. 39.montyslondon.appspot.com.

Answer (score 1):

This bug might have something to do with it:

```
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3062

You can now use https://1-dot-latest-dot-myapp.appspot.com/ in lieu of http://1.latest.myapp.appspot.com/ to get around this problem.
```

It's marked as fixed but that seems like a rubbish fix to me. Will try it anyway and report back.

Comment: This works. Use of the word "latest" is misleading - don't think this version needs to be your latest version.